# HQL update column with COUNT

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hql

I'm working with Hibernate thus HQL, linked to a PostgreSQL database.
I have a table `users` and a table `teams` that are linked with a `ManyToMany` condition throught the table `teams_users`.
I'd like to **update** or **select** the table `team` so the property `usersCount` takes the amount of users belonging to a team.

I do not want to add a `@Formula` to my Entity Class, because I don't want it to be executed *all* the time, that's too wastful on big `JOIN FETCH` query where I do not need the count.

---

I other words, I'd like to find the HQL equivalent of the following PSQL query

```
UPDATE teams t 
SET users_count = (SELECT COUNT(ut.*)
    FROM teams t1 
    LEFT JOIN teams_users tu 
        ON t1.id = tu.team_id 
    WHERE t1.id = t.id 
    GROUP BY t1.id);
```

OR

An equivalent of the following

```
SELECT t.*, count(tu.*) AS users_count 
FROM teams t 
LEFT JOIN teams_users tu 
    ON t.id = tu.team_id 
GROUP BY t.id;
```

---

Unsuccessful tries (to get an idea)

```
UPDATE Team t SET
    t.usersCount = COUNT(t.users)
```

```
UPDATE Team t SET
    t.usersCount = (SELECT COUNT(t1.users) FROM Team t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id)
```

```
SELECT t, count(t.users) AS t.usersCount
FROM Team t
```

Comment: The second query looks good to me. Do you get exception or why are the tries unsuccessful

Comment: @SimonMartinelli with this query is thrown `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement with the cause org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error on or near « . »`

Comment: How do you execute the statement? And how does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: I execute the statement like that   
`em.getTransaction().begin();
em.createQuery("UPDATE Team t SET "
        + "t.usersCount = (SELECT COUNT(t1.users) FROM Team t1 WHERE t1.id = t.id)")
    .executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();`

Comment: The SQL looks like that 
The generated SQL is like that 
`update
        public.teams 
    set
        users_count=(select
            count(.) 
        from
            public.teams team1_ cross 
        join
            public.teams_users users2_, public.users user3_ 
        where
            team1_.id=users2_.team_id 
            and users2_.user_id=user3_.id 
            and (
                user3_.is_active = true
            ) 
            and team1_.id=public.teams.id)`  
The error is in the `count(.)` and the join with the table `users` is obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution for the **UPDATE** query.
It simply is

```
UPDATE Team t 
SET t.usersCount = (SELECT COUNT(u) from t.users u)
```

It makes an extra join on the table `users` whilst the table `teams_users` would be enought but well... It works.

If anyone has ths solution for the **SELECT** one, I'm still curious !